# time series forecasting with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have collected some data which basically encapsulates some internet traffic behaviour like average packet delivery time between two sensors, queue lengths etc. at different times of the day and month.

On top of it, I also have for each of these measurements some labeled value which determines the average delay from the normal delivery times in seconds.

What I would like to do is be able to predict those average delays n the future. So, for me it seems like a two step problem.

- Do time series modelling, so that I can forecast packet delivery times into the future.
- Map those forecasted values into delay and this, I guess, needs to be learnt using some machine learning approach.

First, is this a reasonable approach to tackle this problem? Secondly, given that my input data is a time series, what ML paradigm would fit best for this?

Of course, open to any other approaches that you think may work better!

Comment: ARIMA, e.g., [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/) or similar material may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it would be best to have a deeper description of the variables at stake, to better understand the available resources and the logistics of the problem.

However, if you say that your goal is to forecast delays, just note that those are a time series in themselves; hence, you can directly model them, disregarding delivery times. 
Now, you have two choices:

1. **Parametric modelling**
2. **Non-parametric modelling** (aka *Machine learning*)

the choice of which entirely depends on the resources at hand (do you have reliable covariates? Enough observations?), the logistic of the implementation (do you have to write a production sotware? Will it run on a cloud/PC/Rasperry/...? Are you interested in knowing about the functional form of the relationship?) and indeed, a good exploration of the data.